# Two floated elements, the second element goes outside the width of parent

Tags: html, css

[image]

So as you can see, I have two floated elements, first one 70% width, second one 30%, but the second one goes outside the parent width, how is this posible? I want it to break down.. at the right not to go outside

```css
.first {
  width: 30%
}
.second {
  width: 70%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent clear ">
  <div class="fl first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque, tellus eget sagittis placerat, lectus massa cursus massa, at rhoncus est turpis non libero. Sed vel justo ac nisl suscipit porta. Mauris commodo eleifend volutpat...
  </div>

  <div class="fr second">
    dsdadsaddsadasddsdsadsadasadsdadsaddsadas ddsdsadsadasadsdadsaddsadasddsdsadsadasa
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end parent -->
```

Comment: I added a stack snippet to your question, but note that you had a few typos in your code that you should fix.

Comment: what's the css for the class `parent`? Did you specified `overflow` for `parent` and/or `clear`?

Comment: It's usign the clearfix method, thats all, nothing else, no other styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you cleared the float? Here is somewhat working code.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.first {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.second {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="parent ">
  <div class="fl first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque, tellus eget sagittis placerat, lectus massa cursus massa, at rhoncus est turpis non libero. Sed vel justo ac nisl suscipit porta. Mauris commodo eleifend volutpat...
  </div>

  <div class="fr second">
    dsdadsaddsadasddsdsadsadasadsdadsaddsadas ddsdsadsadasadsdadsaddsadasddsdsadsadasa
  </div>
  <div class=' clear'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume there was an issue with your clearfix. Here is a quick jsfiddle of what you want.

I added a border so you can see it is not going outside the parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/2cggv0sv/

```css
.first {
  width: 30%;
}

.second {
  width: 70%;
}

.fl {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear">

<div class="fl first">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque, tellus eget sagittis placerat, lectus massa cursus massa, at rhoncus est turpis non libero. Sed vel justo ac nisl suscipit porta. Mauris commodo eleifend volutpat...
</div>
<div class="fl second">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque, tellus eget sagittis placerat, lectus massa cursus massa, at rhoncus est turpis non libero. Sed vel justo ac nisl suscipit porta. Mauris commodo eleifend volutpat...
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for the issue in your screenshot, and your provided code example is bugged in another way (the children aren't `float`-ing).

I could only suspect that your elements are using default `box-sizing` value (`box-sizing: content-box;`) while having an absolute value padding on the parent and/or children. Try adding

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to see if the problem is gone.